# Codeigniter Routing fine with one and not another url

Tags: codeigniter

I have my main setup in a sub-folder on my domain called 'main'.

My .htaccess is setup correctly.

My entire site works fine and I can access all my pages.

On my home, I have two search boxes. One does a search by company, the other by state.

The search by state, routes correctly to the sub-folder url, such as:
hxxp://domain.com/main/search/state/All

but my search by company, routes to:
hxxp://domain.com/search/company/All

```
$route['search/province/(:any)'] = "site/search/province/$1";
$route['search/company/(:any)/(:any)'] = "site/search/company/$1/$2";
```

Anyone have any ideas why this would happen?

Here is my htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /main/
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|captcha\.php|captcha|images|img|css|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem.

Seems the form action in a Javascript file was sending it to a hardcoded url. Changing the hardcoding fixed the problem.